# I pass the function as a parameter, while the function itself requires the argument self

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

There is a tab class in which I implement the logic: when the `combox` changes, the Label should also change. To do this, I use a button that is processed by a function with a `combox` check. Since `combox` and Label belong to the self, I also pass the self to this function. However, when passing a function to a button, I cannot specify the arguments in parentheses.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

class TestTab:

    def __init__(self, tab_control):
        self.tab_control = tab_control
        TestTab.TabInitialization(self)


    def TabInitialization(self):
        self.tab = ttk.Frame(self.tab_control)
        self.tab_control.add(self.tab, text='Parser')

        self.lbl = ttk.Label(self.tab, text='') # Here I create Label and Combox
        self.lbl.pack()
        TestTab.Combo(self)
        
    def Combo(self):

        select_frame = ttk.Frame(self.tab)
        select_frame.pack()
    
        VALUES = ('test1', 'test2', 'test3')
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(select_frame, values=VALUES)
        self.combo.current(0)
        self.combo.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

        btn = ttk.Button(select_frame, text='Select', command=TestTab.ModeControll)
        btn.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10) # The problem is here: ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    
    def ModeControll(self):
        if self.combo.get() == 'test1':
            self.lbl.configure(text='test1')
        elif self.combo.get() == 'test2':
            self.lbl.configure(text='test2')
        elif self.combo.get() == 'test3':
            self.lbl.configure(text='test3')
```

Я пробовал передать self через **kwargs
`btn = ttk.Button(select_frame, text='Select', command=TestTab.ModeControll, self_=self)`
or `btn = ttk.Button(select_frame, text='Select', command=TestTab.ModeControll, **self_=self)`

But nothing worked. If you think about it, even if I create another function to redirect to the ModeController, the same function will require self to be passed to the ModeController. So this is a very big headache for me...

Comment: I think it should be `command=self.ModeControll` instead.

Answer (score -1):

From a [comment by acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76198249/i-pass-the-function-as-a-parameter-while-the-function-itself-requires-the-argum/76198397#comment134375251_76198249)

> I think it should be `command=self.ModeControll` instead.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is not an answer.